# Range of arccotangent function

Tags: trigonometry

I know range of arccotangent is $(0,180^{\circ})$ but shouldn't it be actually $( - 90^{\circ}, 90^{\circ})$ as we always take the smallest value in magnitude for the inverse trigonometric functions just like it is done in the rest five of them.

So why is it different for cot inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there exist different conventions on how $\cot^{-1} x$ is defined. The most common definition is defining $\cot^{-1} x$ as the inverse of $\cot(x)$ restricted to the domain $\left(0, \pi\right)$. Another definition that is sometimes used in mathematics software (like Wolfram Mathematica) is $\left(-{\pi\over 2}, {\pi\over 2}\right)$.

You can read more about this issue [on this website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html) provided by Wolfram.